# can i copy catalina.log file logs in another file if yes how to configured with spring server?

Tags: tomcat9

How to manage catalina.log file, if file is reached a particular size (GB) then copy all logs into another file so i will check logs with a new stable file.

please give me solutions to manage logs file.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Are you talking about the `catalina.<current date>.log` file or a file named exactly `catalina.log`? The first is created by Tomcat, the latter might contain the standard error and output of Tomcat (the name depends on the OS).

Comment: in linux
yes i talk about only catalina.log file it's path is > tomcat/logs/catalina.log
i'm talking about at the server running time

Comment: That file probably contains the contents of stderr/stdout. You can use [`logrotate`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html) with the `copytruncate` and `size` options to rotate it.